Unearthing cat buried 2 years ago. What to expect?
Our cat died 2 years ago, and we buried it on our property.
But now we are moving. So my SO wants to unearth it, and move it with us.
I'm gonna guess its not gonna be pretty, but what is there to expect? What would be the best practices to do so?

First, I think it would depend on how the cat was buried. Second, I don't think the question would align with this Stack, maybe Biology.SE.

i think you need to provide a lot more details before this question can be answered,things like the type of soil,the climate where you live,soil moisture,temperature,loose or compacted soil and how exposed to the wind and weather the ground is.

Without more information, 6 months to many years

We mostly deal with the living, not the dead - and really it depends on a lot of things. While we do deal with the immediate aftermath of pet death, not entirely sure if this is on topic for us

To put this the least harsh I can think of. When a pet is unalived, it begins to decompose from weather, insects or other natural processes. That being mentioned, every other answer applies. Soil moisture, p.h. levels and a whole bunch of different factors arise. Short answer, regardless the climate wear a mask. Decomposition is a biohazard!
